# Cookie and image loading issues when switching between http://www.mywebsite.com and http://mywebsite.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cookies

I am having some issues with cookies and images.  The issues seem to arise when I switch between `http://www.mywebsite.com` and `http://mywebsite.com`.  For example, I set some login "remember me" cookies - if I visit `www` and log in, the cookies work just fine.  As soon as I take the `www` away, the cookies disappear.  A quick Inspect Elements in Chrome shows that the cookies are listed under the domain `www.mywebsite.com` and as soon as I switch, they disappear.

I'm wondering if this could be an Apache configuration problem, or something else.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That's by design. `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` are different domains. A cookie set in `www.domain.com` will not be visible in `domain.com`.

While the behaviour can be changed so the cookie covers all subdomains of `domain.com`, there really is no point doing that. The usual way to fix this is to enforce *one* of them - ie. redirecting all `domain.com` traffic to `www` or the other way round. It's also important for avoiding duplicate content

Comment: Thanks.  Is this redirect something that is done with .htaccess, or should I just ensure that all of my links point to `domain.com`, rather than `www.domain.com`?

Comment: @Nick see the accepted answer to the duplicate link above